# Microsoft Sync Framework - How Does Bidirectional Sync Work?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, synchronization, .net-3.5

I have two clients A and B.  Both clients have identical, synced local data caches.

If client A makes an offline edit to record X and then client B also offline edits record X and syncs with the server, when client A syncs with the server, the change that client B made is not reflected and no amount of bidirectional syncing makes the two clients correctly synced with the server.

Other than this, my sync app works great for deletions, additions edits etc.  It's only simultaneous offline edits that destroy integrity.

I am using SQL 2005 (with the necessary SQL scripts for sync support applied)

Is there any resource that explains the nuts and bolts of how sync framework actually works and how it decides when to sync entries?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any resource that explains
>   the nuts and bolts of how sync
>   framework actually works and how it
>   decides when to sync entries?

Have you looked at the [Sync Framework spec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb902834.aspx)? Also [Steve Lasker's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/stevelasker/) has some good tips on OCS and sync framework. He was pretty much the major driving force behind OCS and SF, although he now moved to Cloud.