# Microsoft Sync Framework for SQL Server and Azure, master-slave?

Tags: synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

How does synching between sql server and sql azure databases work if I use Sync Framework?

Does it have a master-slave rule? Or

Does it send bidirectional data in between connection and appends changes to one another?

Comment: I think I found a useful post here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010902/microsoft-sync-framework-how-does-bidirectional-sync-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's up to you, you can hub-spoke (master-slave) or peer-to-peer... you can do upload only, download only or bidirectional.

see: [Synchronizing SQL Azure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff928514.aspx)

and if you want an n-tier setup, have a look at this one as well: [Walkthrough of Windows Azure Sync Service Sample](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1568.walkthrough-of-windows-azure-sync-service-sample.aspx)

Or if you want an out-of-the-box sync solution, have a look at the [Azure SQL Data Sync Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh456371.aspx)