# SQL Server 2014 / Data Sync / Offline application

Tags: sql, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework, offline-caching, sql-server-2014

I'm looking for CURRENT advice/information on how to manage an offline client that will sync changes to the cloud. I would love to find an example using SQL Server 2014.

Primarily the client app is a data collection device that will upload the data collected.  AS there will be many devices collecting data I'm anticipating lots of data going up, but only reference data coming down (no point in syncing all the data being collected to all the devices).

I've searched the web and Stackoverflow, and only have found information on the Sync framework dating back to 2010, which sounds really old to me.  My gut is telling me that Sync 2.1 (last release was 8/18/2010 (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23217)

I've reviewed these links (as well as many others):

[Developer Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb736753.aspx)

[Sync Blog - 3years old](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sync/)

[Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13738900/microsoft-sync-framework-for-sql-server-and-azure-master-slave)

I'm using an Azure SQL Server Standard Edition VM (as I also need SSRS hosted) in the cloud.  Clients are WPF (maybe reach for Win8) applications running on Win8 tables, .Net 4.5, and SQL Server Version 12.0.2000 (not compact).

I built a prototype, and the only "real" problem that I don't fully understand is the Sync framework, as I can only achieve a "sync" with the sync direction of UploadAndDownload. Upload or Download by itself will not work.

Comment: can you clarify what doesn't work with Upload and Download being done separately? internally UploadAndDownload is a separate Upload followed by a Download.

Comment: If I did Upload and download separately, the stats would show that nothing moved. If I did the uploadanddownload scope, the sync would happen.  the upload and download had a scope of a couple of tables, and the syncall scope had all the tables.  Since I asked this question, I've given up on the framework.  Just not enough information coming out of it - 94 hours later - I have my own sync process, and a rewritten application!

Comment: if you have tables in multiple scopes, chances are you run into conflicts.

Comment: reason? Documentation that provides this guidance? Tks.

Comment: sync knowledge is kept per scope, what the other scope has synched, the other scopes has no idea. if a table belongs to two scope and first one downloads a row, then the second scope syncs, it will download the row again and will result to a conflict.

Comment: Is it an option to use SQLite for your local data?  If so, consider Azure Mobile Services which offers an offline sync solution (http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/Mobile-services-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-offline-data/). This will work on WPF/WinRT/WinPhone/Xamarin. (Disclosure: I work on this product.)